# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: in DJango application

Tags: django, database, postgresql

I am working with a Django application with Postgres Database.

My models are as follows:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User as UserModel
from dynamicforms.mangers import TextQuestionManager, MCQManager, IntegerQuestionManager
from django.db.models.fields.related import OneToOneRel
from django.contrib.postgres import fields as postgres_fields

Qtypes = [(1, "Multiple Choice Question"), (2, "Text Question"), (3, "integer Type Question")]
COMPS = [(True, 'Yes'), (False, 'No')]
SECTIONS = [(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5)]


class QuestionModel(models.Model):
    qtype = models.IntegerField(null=False, choices=Qtypes)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=500, null=False, blank=False)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    help_text = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    is_compulsory = models.BooleanField(default=True, null=False, choices=COMPS)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text


class TextQuestionModel(QuestionModel):
    nextQ = postgres_fields.ArrayField(models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True), null=True, blank=True)
    objects = TextQuestionManager()


class MCQModel(QuestionModel):
    objects = MCQManager()

    class Meta:
        proxy = True


class IntegerQuestionModel(QuestionModel):
    nextQ = postgres_fields.ArrayField(models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True), null=True, blank=True)
    objects = IntegerQuestionManager()
```

I made few changes to my schema.So i have to reset my DB.I reseted my DB and migrations and when im trying to run

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

I am getting this error.I tried changing db and changing user and everything.I dont understand what made this error.

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <_pydev_bundle.pydev_monkey._NewThreadStartupWithTrace instance at 0x7fa990057998>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/pycharm/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_monkey.py", line 553, in __call__
    return self.original_func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/home/phani/Projects/Freewill/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/phani/Projects/Freewill/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 113, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/phani/Projects/Freewill/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "/home/phani/Projects/Freewill/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/phani/Projects/Freewill/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/phani/Projects/Freewill/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 115, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/home/phani/Projects/Freewill/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/apps.py", line 23, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "/home/phani/Projects/Freewill/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 26, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "/home/phani/Projects/Freewill/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 50, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/phani/Projects/Freewill/dynamicforms/admin.py", line 3, in <module>
    from dynamicforms.forms import MCQFormAdmin, TextFormAdmin, IntegerFormAdmin
  File "/home/phani/Projects/Freewill/dynamicforms/forms.py", line 6, in <module>
    QS = [(i.id, i.text) for i in QuestionModel.objects.all()]
  File "/home/phani/Projects/Freewill/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 256, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/phani/Projects/Freewill/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1087, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/home/phani/Projects/Freewill/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 54, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql()
  File "/home/phani/Projects/Freewill/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 835, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/phani/Projects/Freewill/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/phani/Projects/Freewill/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/phani/Projects/Freewill/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/phani/Projects/Freewill/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "dynamicforms_questionmodel" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."dynamicforms_questionmodel"."is_compulsory" FROM "dynamicfo...
                                                             ^
```

Can someone help me with this?Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You reseted all files in project. But migrations history saved in django_migrations tables . You also must clean this table.
Are you deleted 'migrations' folder in your app?

Comment: yes,but i cant find django_migrations table in postgres

Comment: can you show "Installed_apps" list in your settings.py file?

Comment: which version python and django?

Comment: python-2.7.12,django-1.10.6
`
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'dynamicforms',
    'accounts',
    'surveys',
)
`

Comment: These are My databases
`
 List of databases
    Name     |    Owner     | Encoding | Collate | Ctype |   Access privileges   
 myappnamedb  | myappuser | UTF8     | en_IN   | en_IN | 
 postgres    | postgres     | UTF8     | en_IN   | en_IN | 
 template0   | postgres     | UTF8     | en_IN   | en_IN | =c/postgres          +
             |              |          |         |       | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1   | postgres     | UTF8     | en_IN   | en_IN | =c/postgres          +
             |              |          |         |       | postgres=CTc/postgres
`

Comment: please, comment your app names in list and  run `python manage.py migrate`.

Comment: running `python manage.py migrate` giving me the same error as i specified in the question
Apps are __accounts,dynamicforms,surveys__

Comment: before run this command comment app names in INSTALLED_APPS 
if you comment this lines ( 'dynamicforms', 'accounts', 'surveys', ) and then run migrate command you can not get same error.

not comment here)) comment in list

Comment: After commenting all the apps i am getting this error
`RuntimeError: Model class dynamicforms.models.QuestionModel doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.`

Comment: running `python manage.py migrate` you get this error
`RuntimeError: Model class dynamicforms.models.QuestionModel doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.` ??

Comment: yes after i commented all my apps im getting that error

Comment: any table are created in your db?

Comment: \dt giving me
`postgres=# \dt
No relations found.
`

Comment: delete current database, delete all 'migrations' folders in your apps.Create new fresh database,uncomment app names in INSTALLED_APPS  list and run `python manage.py makemigrations`

Comment: Same as i mentioned in Question
Whenever dynamicforms is mentioned in django.Im getting error.But without that app migrations worked fine

Comment: If you are doing it in order, you shouldn't get again same error :/
Please comment is_compulsory field in class run makemigrations again

Comment: if i comment is_compulsory field i am getting same error for other field in model :/

Comment: `from dynamicforms.mangers import TextQuestionManager, MCQManager, IntegerQuestionManager` what for you are using this

Comment: I copy your model. commented just this ` from dynamicforms.mangers import TextQuestionManager, MCQManager, IntegerQuestionManager` line and objects . after run makemigrations get success result

Comment: check also this command `python manage.py makemigrations dynamicforms`

Comment: Thanks for the help.I resolved the issue.In my forms i refernced for QuestionModel for choices.That caused this error.Now i can migrate database.Thanks for the help and yur precious time